# Excel formula to Find the last cell with value in a row and add to adjacent cell if there aren't blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a formula in excel which will find the last cell that has a value and then it to check if the adjacent cells have value and if it has values then it should show the sum until it reaches a blank cell in the reverse direction on cell O1 and also should show the count of the cell in P1.

[image]

Comment: Tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64504723/4961700

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, this what I have tried and works, use the below formulas, to accomplish the output you are looking for,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `O2` --> To get the sum of the values from back until a blank has been found towards left.

```
=SUM(INDEX(B2:M2,MATCH(2,1/ISBLANK(INDEX(B2:M2,1):
INDEX(B2:M2,MATCH(2,B2:M2,1)))))
:INDEX(B2:M2,MATCH(2,B2:M2,1)))
```

• Formula used in cell `P2` --> To get the counts.

```
=COUNT(INDEX(B2:M2,MATCH(2,1/ISBLANK(INDEX(B2:M2,1):
INDEX(B2:M2,MATCH(2,B2:M2,1))))):
INDEX(B2:M2,MATCH(2,B2:M2,1)))
```

**Note:** Array formulas needs to be committed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and fill down!!!